# How to lookup variables declared in Spring applications.yml file in log4j2.xml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have a tiered application properties system. The main applications.yml contains info about which environment to work in, e.g. dev:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

And then there's an applications-dev.yml file which contains the variables that I want:

```
pulsar:
  server:
    connection:
      url: pulsar://172.21.11.79:6650
```

I want to reference `pulsar.server.connection.url` in my log4j2.xml file.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="PULSAR_URL">${spring:pulsar.server.connection.url}</Property>
</Properties>
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work mean"?  Did you include the log4j-spring-cloud-config-client jar?

Comment: Yes it has conflict with my other logger dependencies, `ignite-log4j2` and `pulsar-log4j2-appender`

Comment: Yes - this is the first question I saw and then found you had created 3 other questions that are all essentially the same but contain different information. If you had put them all together it would made helping you easier.